# How best to deploy this multi-tier app?

Tags: openshift

We currently have an application that runs on one dedicated server. I'd like to move it to OpenShift. It has:

1. A public-facing web app written in PhP
2. A Java app for administrators running on Wildfly
3. A Mysql database
4. A filesystem containing lots of images and documents that must be accessible to both the Java and PhP apps. A third party ftp's a data file to the server every day, and a perl script loads that into the db and the file system.
5. A perl script occasionally runs ffmpeg to generate videos, reading images from and writing videos to the filesystem.

Is Openshift a good solution for this, or would it be better to use AWS directly instead (for instance because they have dedicated file system components?)

Thanks
Michael Davis
Ottawa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared file system will definitely be the biggest issue here.  You could get around it by setting up your applications to use Amazon S3 or some other shared Cloud file system though fairly easily.

As for the rest of the application, if I were setting this up I would:
Setup a scaled PHP application, even if you set the scaling to just use 1 gear this will allow you to put the MySQL database on it's own gear, and even choose a different size for it, such as having medium web gears (that run php) and a large gear that runs the MySQL database.  This will also allow your wildfly gear to access the database since it will have a FQDN (fully qualified domain name) that any of your applications on your account can reach.  However, keep in mind that it will use a non-standard port instead of 3306.

Then you can setup your WildFly server as whatever size you want, but, keep in mind that the MySQL connection variables will not be there, you will have to put them into your java application manually.

As for the perl script, depending on how intensive it is, you could run it on it's own whatever sized gear with some extra storage, or you could co-locate it with either the php or java application as a cron job.  You can have it store the files on Amazon S3 and pull them down/upload them as it does the ffmpeg operations on them.  Since OpenShift is also hosted on Amazon (In the US-EAST region) these operations should be pretty fast, as long as you also put your S3 bucket in the US-EAST region.

Those are my thoughts, hope it helps.  Feel free to ask questions if you have them.  You can also visit http://help.openshift.com and under "Contact Us" click on "Submit a request" and make sure you reference this StackOverflow question so I know what you are talking about, you can ask any questions you might have and we can discuss solutions for them.

Comment: That's very useful, thanks. The one part I wasn't clear on was the file system - it hadn't occurred to me to mix and match OpenShift with AWS, but why not?

Comment: Each OpenShift gear has it's own filesystem, even if it's in a scaled application, and they can not access each others files in the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, or files that get uploaded by users.  So having your code interact with Amazon S3 would be a way around that.  There are lots of libraries for it already, like paperclip for Rails.